# Netty Client can't receive the message from server

Tags: netty

Here is my Server code

```java
public class Server {
    private int port;

    public Server(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run() {
        NioEventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        NioEventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        ServerBootstrap server = new ServerBootstrap();
        try {
            server
                    .group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                            pipeline
                                    .addLast(new StringDecoder())
                                    .addLast(new StringEncoder())
                                    .addLast(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                                            System.out.println("get msg from :" + ctx.channel().remoteAddress() + " : " + msg);
                                            ctx.channel().writeAndFlush("msg received");
                                            System.out.println("write back!");
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    });
            ChannelFuture cf = server.bind(port).sync();

            cf.channel().closeFuture().sync();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("end");
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server(9998).run();
    }
}
```

Here is my Client code

```java
public class Client {
    private String host;
    private int port;

    public Client(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run(){
        NioEventLoopGroup  group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        try{
            bootstrap
                    .group(group)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                            pipeline
                                    .addLast("decoder",new StringDecoder())
                                    .addLast("encoder",new StringEncoder())
                                    .addLast(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter(){
                                        @Override
                                        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                                            System.out.println(msg);
                                        }
                                    });

                        }
                    });
            ChannelFuture cf = bootstrap.connect(host, port).sync();
            Channel client = cf.channel();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String content = null;
            while(!(content = reader.readLine()).equals("exit")){
                client.writeAndFlush(content);
            }

            client.closeFuture().sync();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Client("127.0.0.1",9998).run();
    }
}
```

The problem is that client can't received the reply from server

[image]

And the interesting part is the client actually can get and print the reply when I run it step by step in debug mode! It's driving me crazy

update---
It's working now, after running in the debug mode... But why???

Environment:
MacOS version 14.0
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1